# I went to prison; do I file taxes for that period?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax

I was incarcerated from 2012 to 2014. Am I supposed to file taxes and if so how do I file or what do I file under since I paroled. I'm from Stockton CA. I await an answer.

Comment: Are you asking if you need to file for the years you were in prison, or are you asking about filing now that you are out?

Answer (score 8):

[Being incarcerated is irrelevant](http://people.opposingviews.com/file-taxes-inmates-7267.html). You have to file taxes if you earn enough income to be required to file taxes. Most inmates won't earn enough, but it is quite possible you have income from other sources.

The minimum income beyond which you are required to file depends on your filing status, your age, and the year. It's just below $10,000 for 2012, and [now appears to be just a little over](http://www.efile.com/tax/do-i-need-to-file-a-tax-return/), assuming you are single and under 65.

If in doubt, I'd recommend filing. If you don't owe anything, it won't cost you anything other than the hassle of filing. Again, there's nothing different about filing because you were incarcerated, it just may be more of a hassle to gather the information you need.

Comment: (and good luck with your parole!)

Comment: Indeed, just fill in some zeros and be on the safe side of things.

Comment: I'm curious; do prisons provide tax forms and publications to inmates?